# What grammar based parser-generator tools exist for ruby?

Tags: ruby, parsing

**What open source (preferably gem-based) parser-generator options do I have in Ruby?**

I've used (flex&bison)|(lex&yacc) from C in the past, and I'm comfortable with BNF-style specifications.

I've heard of treetop, but it looks a bit alien and verbose compared to yacc...

**Purpose:** I want to convert my text markup language to a BNF and generate the parsing code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at [rex](http://rubygems.org/gems/rex) and [racc](http://rubygems.org/gems/racc), the gem versions of lex and yacc?

Answer (score 3):

There's also [parslet](http://kschiess.github.io/parslet/) if you want a PEG-based processor

Answer (score 1):

[Citrus](https://github.com/mjijackson/citrus) is an option - similar but not identical to [Treetop](https://github.com/nathansobo/treetop) in its grammar.